# Converting an Uploaded File to PNG

Tags: python, django, django-models, python-imaging-library, image-uploading

I have a Django form where a User uploads a file. I've been trying to first verify that the file is of the acceptable format (jpg, png, or tiff) and then convert the file to png. I'm using PIL but keep getting stuck. In my latest attempt, I can't figure out how to convert the Image back to a File so that the File can be saved to the model in my view. How can I do that?

Here is the `def clean_image(self)` method of my form:

```
    image = self.cleaned_data.get('my_image')
    if image:
        imagetype = imghdr.what(image)
        if image._size > 4*1024*1024:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Image is too large. Please select an image < 4mb")
        else:
            if imagetype not in ('jpeg, jpg, png, tiff'):
                raise forms.ValidationError("Only jpeg, png, or tiff file types can be uploaded.")
            # convert image to png regardless of initial upload state
            #size = (130, 130)
            try:
                i = Image.open(image)
                i.load()
                converted = Image.new("RGB", i.size)
                converted_name = str(image).split('.')[0] + ".png"
                converted.save(converted_name, "PNG")
            except IOError:
                raise forms.ValidationError("There was a problem saving your image. Only jpeg, png, or tiff file < 4mb types can be uploaded.")

            return converted
```

Comment: `clean_foo` is just for field validation, you shouldn't process the file in there. Why don't you use the `upload_to` function to convert the file? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to

Comment: Ah, ok, thank you @ShangWang I imagine I will still have the same underlying issue, though, once I move the processing elsewhere. If I just return `image = self.cleaned_data.get('dataset_image')` from the clean method, I can already save it just fine. But, how can I fix the file vs image issue?